# Exclude lines within t_sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

[image]

I need to exclude all lines where having  `round( sum(QtyInvoiced),1) = 0 and round(sum(Amount),1) =0`

[image]

I try the following script but it dosen't work, how to correct it?

```
 select sum(    QtyInvoiced ) , sum(Amount) ,salesNumber 
    from invoicesales
   group by salesNumber 
    except 

    select sum( QtyInvoiced ) , sum(Amount) ,salesNumber 
    from invoicesales

    group by salesNumber 

    having round( sum(QtyInvoiced),1) = 0 and round(sum(Amount),1) =0
```

Comment: What does *"it dosen't work"* mean? Did you get an error, unexpected result, undesired behaviour, something else?

Comment: I get always the lines where amount and qtyinvoiced = 0

Comment: did you maybe mean `OR`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I mean and,, the both measures shouald be equal to 0.

Comment: *"I get always the lines where amount and qtyinvoiced = 0"* but that is **exactly** what you've asked for: `round( sum(QtyInvoiced),1) = 0 and round(sum(Amount),1) =0`. If the sum of `QtyInvoiced` **and** the sum of `Amount` equal 0 (rounded to 1 decimal place, and within the group defined by the `GROUP BY`), the row will be returned; otherwise it will be filtered out by the `HAVING`.

Comment: Try including the `round()` values in the query that shows all the rows, so you can see what's happening at that stage of the query.

Comment: I see two answers that work around the issue, but I'd love to see an explanation of why the EXCEPT isn't working the way csharp expects.   Seems to me it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like below using <> not equal

```
select sum( QtyInvoiced ) , sum(Amount) ,salesNumber 
from invoicesales
group by salesNumber 
having round( sum(QtyInvoiced),1) <> 0 and round(sum(Amount),1)<>0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **exclude** those rows, perhaps you want a `NOT`?

```
HAVING NOT(ROUND( SUM(QtyInvoiced),1) = 0 AND ROUND(SUM(Amount),1) = 0);
```

Otherwise yes, your SQL will do *exactly* what you've asked for to return the rows where the sum of `QtyInvoiced` **and** `Amount` **equals** `0` (not exclude those that do).

Comment: I don't understand, why isn't the EXCEPT filtering out those rows as the OP expects?   Did you not notice the EXCEPT in the original code?   It should be filtering those rows out, not including them.

Comment: Not sure, in truth @TabAlleman . I'm not going to transcribe the OP's data, but i wouldn't be surprised if it's overly simplified. Either way, they don't actually need an `EXCEPT` here.